# Windows 7 PowerShell Iterate files in a folder and print out values of certain xml tags

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I have a folder structure as shown as follows.

[image: Folder hierarchy]

What I would like to do is, iterate through subfolders and find feature.xml, if any, and finally print out the value of certain xml tag. Let's say Feature.xml contains tag like this

```
<foo>need to pull this value</foo>
```

For this simple example, i just need to print out "need to pull this value" or any values contained in foo tag of feature.xml files.

Any help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if the foo start tag, content and close tag are all on the same line:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Mainfolder -Filter Feature.xml -Recurse | % {
    if ($_ -match '<foo>(.*?)</foo>') { 
        $Matches[1] 
    } 
}
```

If foo is  multiline (`<foo>` and `</foo>` on different lines), try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Mainfolder -Filter Feature.xml -Recurse | % {
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)
    $xml.SelectNodes("//foo") | % { $_."#text" } 
}
```

Comment: np. I forgot `-Recurse`, but I guess you figured it out yourself =)

Comment: I used bit different approach as I had to crawl through various types of folder and files, but your script gave me a really good start :)